# Does algorithm time complexity O(5) considered as O(1)?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I have someone homework to make and in the instructions it says that we need to implement a function in O(1).

Now, does it mean that I can make my function in O(5) or O(2) or whatever?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it answerable.  I don't even know why you would need to know this to do your homework.

Comment: You have someone's homework to make? Or some homework?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, O(5) is the same thing as O(1). If you've been asked to implement a function in O(1) time, it means it needs to run in the same amount of time no matter how large the data being provided to it is.